# Export Azure Dev Ops Wiki data

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, automation

I have recently joined a company that has no Azure Dev Ops wiki, but they do have tons of documented processes which they keep within a sharepoint library. I've spoken to other members of the company and they've been trying to convince management to allow the use of a DevOps wiki for ages, to no avail.

No idea how i did it, but now we have permission to start using it to hold "how to's" in using dev ops, creating pipelines, managing work items etc, on the proviso that information about the wiki can be kept back on a sharepoint list somewhere as a directory.

What management want is:

Name (of wiki page)
URL
Last Updated

and every time a wiki is updated, it updates the directory.

This is so the wiki page can be accessed from the directory, as well as the current sharepoint document library.

I've had a look and there are lots of solutions on how to clone the wiki or create PDF's or word documents from it, but not the data of the wiki rather than the content itself.

Powerautomate doesn't seem to have any connections or triggers to the wiki, so i'm stuck.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to synchronize the files from your Azure DevOps wiki into SharePoint site folder. However, based on your requirements, you may test with the sample pipeline below.

1. We need to **trigger** such synchronization workflow automatically, whenever a wiki page is updated (i.e. new commit is pushed to the .md wiki files in the project wiki repository); for this, we copy and paste the wiki repo URL into the browser address bar and then we can proceed to `Set up Build` with this wiki repo (to enable `CI` trigger);

[image]

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - wikiMaster
  paths:
    include:
    - /**/*.md
    - /*.md

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
- powershell: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /F /A
    Write-Host "================1. Get the updated file path of the triggering commit ================"
    $headers = @{
      Authorization = "bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
    }
    $commitChangeURL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/TheProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/TheProjectName.wiki/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)/changes?api-version=7.2-preview.1"
    Write-Host "commitChangeURL is $commitChangeURL"
    $commitChangeResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commitChangeURL -Method GET -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose
    
    Write-Host "================2. Get the page URL ================"
    foreach ($change in $commitChangeResponse.changes) {
        If ($change.item.gitObjectType -eq "blob"){
            $path = $change.item.path
            Write-Host "Updated .md file Path is $path"
            $wikiPageName = ($path -split '\.')[0]
            Write-Host "wikiPageName is $wikiPageName"
            $getWikiPageURL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/TheProjectName/_apis/wiki/wikis/TheProjectName.wiki/pages?path=$wikiPageName&api-version=7.2-preview.1"
            $getWikiPageResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getWikiPageURL -Method GET -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose # | ConvertFrom-Json
            $wikiPageId = $getWikiPageResponse.id
            Write-Host "The wiki page URL is $(System.CollectionUri)/TheProjectName/_wiki/wikis/TheProjectName.wiki/$wikiPageId"
        }
    }
  displayName: Get updated wiki page URL
- task: az-pipelines-2-sharepoint@0
  displayName: Upload the files from System.DefaultWorkingDirectory to SharePoint site
  inputs:
    tenantId: '$(TenantId)'
    clientId: '$(ClientId)'
    clientSecret: '$(ClientSecret)'
    driveId: 'https://$(SharePointOnline).sharepoint.com/sites/AzureDevOpsTeamSite/Shared%20Documents/'
    targetFolder: 'AzureDevOpsProjectWiki'
    sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    contents: '**'
    conflictBehaviour: 'replace'
    cleanTargetFolder: true
    flattenFolders: false
    failOnEmptySource: false
- task: az-pipelines-2-sharepoint@0
  displayName: Upload the files from System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/.attachments to SharePoint site
  inputs:
    tenantId: '$(TenantId)'
    clientId: '$(ClientId)'
    clientSecret: '$(ClientSecret)'
    driveId: 'https://$(SharePointOnline).sharepoint.com/sites/AzureDevOpsTeamSite/Shared%20Documents/'
    targetFolder: 'AzureDevOpsProjectWiki/.attachments'
    sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.attachments'
    contents: '**'
    conflictBehaviour: 'replace'
    cleanTargetFolder: true
    flattenFolders: false
    failOnEmptySource: false
```

2. We need to know the updated wiki page URL; for this, we can call the APIs [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) and [Pages - Get Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get-page?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) in the `powershell` pipeline task to know the updated wiki page URL based on the triggering commit `$(Build.SourceVersion)`;
3. We can use the **3rd-party** extension [Upload files to SharePoint Online - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=halliba.az-pipelines-2-sharepoint) to clear SharePoint target folder first and upload all files from the working directory on the pipeline agent onto the SharePoint target folder; See for more details on how the task authenticates access to sharepoint against [App registration in Azure AD](https://github.com/halliba/az-pipelines-2-sharepoint#app-registration-in-azure-ad).
4. The task seems to ignore all the files and folders whose names begin with `.`; for this, I add another task to upload files from `.attachments` directory of the wiki repo;

[image]

Since the workflow will first remove all contents from the SharePoint target folder, please use a SharePoint directory **for test** before integrating the workflow with your production contents to **avoid accidental deletion of data**

Comment: This is great, thank you for taking the time to reply, I'll get on with this and come back if i have any issues.

Comment: Hi Alvin, your info was added to a backlog item so we can add it to a future sprint, i'll let you know if it worked and what we did when it gets planned in.

Comment: Hi @AntonyL, Thanks for your taking time to share the update. I have added path filter `/*.md` to trigger the pipeline workflow, since I noticed the commit on ProjectWiki page (not sub page) in the Project wiki repo could not trigger the pipeline. Hope the solution can help address your query and benefit others with similar requests. Cheers!